# Armature Doesn't Move Mesh Properly when in Pose Mode?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

So when I move my master bone in any direction, my characters eyes move farther than the distance I moved

Here's my file https://pasteall.org/blend/b3474565319c4e57afb0f0269e2f58e1

Here is rig without any movement

[image]

Then I move it in the y axis and the eyes move out of the correct position. This only happens after I parent the eye bones to my master bone. The eyes should be in the position of the black eye lids.

[image]

If I remove the master bone as a parent from my eye bone, the eye stays in the character rig properly, however, the eye bone just stays in one spot now. NOTE I only removed the master bone from the left eye to show the effect. The right eye still has the master bone parented hence it moved farther away

[image]

Lastly, when I rotate the spine, the eyes move correctly, yet the eyelids just stay in one place?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your eyes are parented twice to the armature: with the *Armature* modifier (*Set Parent to > Armature Deform* options) and with a classic parenting (*Set Parent to > Bone*), you need to choose one or the other (remove the classic parenting with an <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or remove the modifier).

Comment: ah so if I remove the armature modifier the eyes move now properly, however, if I were to rotate my spine forward, the eyes no longer rotate and are only stationary. Is there a way to make them rotate with the spine too?

Comment: you need to make sure that the eye bones are parented to the good bone in Edit mode

Comment: so I parented them to the spine and they rotate when I move the spine, however my mesh deforms slightly on rotate hence the eyes get out of position. Normally I would parent the eyes to my character body, however on armatures it doesn't allow for that and only allows parents to other bones. The only way is if I delete some spine bones so it doesn't bend as much, but idk if theres a solution besides that

Comment: It's hard to help through BlenderStackExchange, I think you need to parent the eyes bones to the head bone, is it what's you've done?

Comment: the problem is my character is a box design where the head is also the face and spine and only the arms and legs are sticking out. So when you rotate him forward it crunches his face and hence the eye socket gets move out of position whereas a normaly character with a neck doesnt have that issue because the head never gets crunched when bending, only the neck. But my guy doesn't have a neck its just all one thing combined